# plotting points with geom_point() and gmap()

Tags: r, ggplot2, qmap

I have 20 UTM locations included below.
**EDIT** I have modified the included data to include the locations in Lat Long and added additional code below.  I get the same result with either UTMs or Lat, Long.  I have double checked the points in google earth and they are certainly within the extent of the BaseMap I define below.  Any other suggestions...

```
    Data <- structure(list(Latitude = c(43.383819, 43.383787, 43.383838, 
43.384088, 43.392086, 43.393099, 43.388453, 43.384829, 43.399706, 
43.40308, 43.408739, 43.40765, 43.407522, 43.413508, 43.418288, 
43.416157, 43.417822, 43.417221, 43.417209, 43.417603), Longitude = c(-111.130989, 
-111.130988, -111.130996, -111.129578, -111.122884, -111.12143, 
-111.126514, -111.12809, -111.125333, -111.126616, -111.139745, 
-111.140401, -111.140614, -111.161305, -111.158135, -111.153607, 
-111.141158, -111.13867, -111.138528, -111.138884), UTM_E = c(489389.998429055, 
489390.073847615, 489389.434748439, 489504.334690555, 490047.849470232, 
490165.770080405, 489753.250369502, 489624.98731782, 489850.781221576, 
489747.455360571, 488685.407063201, 488632.089708587, 488614.819667178, 
486940.804672798, 487198.453753294, 487564.574155778, 488572.710048877, 
488774.012335271, 488785.505688775, 488756.758707237), UTM_N = c(4803447.00888757, 
4803443.45497495, 4803449.11983808, 4803476.70438902, 4804364.10875695, 
4804476.43597084, 4803961.08216192, 4803558.81058659, 4805210.65084223, 
4805585.51119635, 4806215.67635871, 4806094.82531047, 4806080.6391722, 
4806748.45554565, 4807278.81358453, 4807041.46688704, 4807224.59410279, 
4807157.51112311, 4807156.15933319, 4807199.96352795)), .Names = c("Latitude", 
"Longitude", "UTM_E", "UTM_N"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I can plot them in using `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(aes(x = UTM_E, y = UTM_N), data = Data )+ geom_point()
ggplot(aes(x = Latitude, y = Longitude), data = Data )+ geom_point()
```

However I want to plot them over a map base layer using `qmap` and have specified the object below.

```
library(ggmap)
Area <- "palisades wyoming"
BaseMap <- qmap(Area , zoom = 10)
BaseMap
```

Following the helpful ggmap site [linked here](http://stat405.had.co.nz/ggmap.pdf), I am trying to plot the points over the base map with the following code

```
BaseMap + geom_point(aes(x = UTM_E, y = UTM_N), data = Data )
BaseMap + geom_point(aes(x = Latitude, y = Longitude), data = Data )
```

but get the following warning

```
Removed 20 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

Why are the values missing when not mapped with `ggplot()`, but only included with `geom_point()`

Mapping the points within `ggplot()` return the following error incompatability between `ggplot()` and `qmap()`

```
BaseMap + ggplot(aes(x = UTM_E, y = UTM_N), data = Data )+ geom_point()

Error in p + o : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("+.gg", "Ops.data.frame") for "+"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably the values are off the edges of your map. When  you use `ggplot`, it is your point data that determines the limits of your plot. When you get a map first, the map sets the limits, and your data happens to go beyond those limits, so the warning is telling you they're not plotted.

Comment: `ggplot` and `qmap` both set up a plot from scratch, you can't combine them. I think `qmap` expects to use units of latitude and longitude. Your data is in UTM, so I would try converting first to lat/long.

Comment: Indeed, `ggmap` is looking for lat/lon. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/ggmap.pdf. https://sites.google.com/a/lakeheadu.ca/yong-luo/blog/convert-utm-to-longlat-in-r may help with the conversion.

Comment: You have long and lat switched. Try `x = Longitude, y = Latitude` and it should work.

Comment: Perfect @ Gregor.  Thanks for pointing out my silly oversight!  I would gladly accept an answer...

Comment: Better to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them. Don't add your map to an object, just call it with the geom_point code:

```
qmap(Area , zoom = 10) + geom_point(aes(x = UTM_E, y = UTM_N), data = Data )
```

And you'll get your map printed.

Good Luck!